# Get Current Value of Select Field

Tags: java, testing, testng, selenium-webdriver

I have a website I am trying to test which has several drop downs. One select element is below:

```
<select class="input-xxlarge" name="dosage">
  <option value="20 MG, Enteric Coated Capsule">20 MG, Enteric Coated Capsule</option>
  <option value="60 MG, Enteric Coated Capsule">60 MG, Enteric Coated Capsule</option>
  <option value="30 MG, Enteric Coated Capsule">30 MG, Enteric Coated Capsule</option>
</select>
```

The only thing which I have noticed which changes after I change the value is the class name changes to: "input-xxlarge changedInput".

I am  running a test with WebDriver and would like to get what the current value is. I have tried to do the following:

```
    WebElement strengthForm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/article[2]/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum2+"]/td/div/article/section/form/fieldset/label/select"));
    String strengthBeforeChoosing = strengthForm.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(strengthBeforeChoosing);
```

The problem is that rather than grabbing the current value, this is giving me all of the options.

20 MG, Enteric Coated Capsule
60 MG, Enteric Coated Capsule
30 MG, Enteric Coated Capsule

How would I go about getting just the current value of the drop down so I can compare it to the current value after I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dosage")));
String selectedText = select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```